# A section of a subset of $[0,\infty[\times \Omega$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The following is the definition of a section.

[image]

(Remark: I don't know how to do in latex the symbol for the graph of the stopping time $T$ above)

Afterwards, the author gives the example that if $A=[[S,S']]$, then $T=(S+S')/2$ is a section of $A$.

My doubt is that when we have $\exists_{t<\infty} (t,\omega) \in A$, then we immediately have $S(\omega)\leq T(\omega)\leq S'(\omega)$. However, why would we have $T(\omega)<\infty$?

Comment: It isn't supported in MathJax, but the latex command for the graph symbol used in that definition is `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` with `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` in the preamble.

Comment: You are correct: On the event $\{S'=\infty\}$ the recipe $(S+S')/2$ yields $\infty$ as well, which fails to result in a "section" 0f $A$. (Out of curiosity: What's the source of this definition?)

Comment: @JohnDawkins Elliot and Cohen's "Stochastic Calculus and Applications"